# Get auto brightness value and auto lock time value

Tags: ios, iphone, brightness, screen-lock

Hi  i'm trying to get 2 value from iOS device,it doesn't really matter what OS version is it.
I need to get if the device's auto brightness is enabled/disabled and the second value of the auto lock screen.
I read over the internet that it is not possible to get these values with public APIs but I want to know if there any way to get these values private API or any other framework,anything which isn't jailbreak or something like that because the app won't be upload to App-store anyway,just for a group of people use.